# Custom axis marks in double logarithmic plot

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I'm getting quite frustrated with my lack of pgfplot understanding and was hoping somebody could help me figure out how to get more readily readable/understandable x axis tick marks. I have the following: [image: Bad axis]

But what I want is the x axis to read more clearly like 2e-3 or even 0.002 instead of the 10^-2.6 which is hardly intuitive. I tried playing around with "x tick label" but it didn't seem to have any influence on the plot! Thanks in advance for your help!

This is the code I'm using to create the graph:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF8 encoding
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{every axis plot}
\pgfplotsset{grid style=dotted}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
    [clip marker paths=true,legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north},
    legend columns=2,
    xlabel=field amplitude,
    ylabel=losses,
    xmin=2e-3, xmax=5e-2,
    ymin=1e-4, ymax=1e-1,
    grid=major
    ]

    \addplot [sharp plot,mark=none, color=black,dotted] table[skip first n=2,x expr=\thisrow{x},y expr=\thisrow{y}]
        {Comp_DataSim.eins.table};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I uploaded the data here:
http://pastebin.com/1zzgtQ2f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can play around with the `pgf/number format/` key described in the manual of `pgfplotstable` to achieve various results.

Two examples :

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF8 encoding
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{every axis plot}
\pgfplotsset{grid style=dotted}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
    [clip marker paths=true,legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north},
    legend columns=2,
    xlabel=field amplitude,
    ylabel=losses,
    xmin=2e-3, xmax=5e-2,
    ymin=1e-4, ymax=1e-1,
    xtick={2e-3,5e-3,1e-2,2e-2,5e-2},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3},
    xticklabel={%
      \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\tick}%
      \pgfmathfloatexp{\pgfmathresult}%
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
    },
    grid=major
    ]

  % Below is a dummy plot so that the MWE is self-contained
  % Anyway, only the axes matter, right? :-)
  \addplot+ coordinates
  {(0,1)
  (5,2)
  (10,3)
  (50,4)
  (100,5)
  (500,6)
  (1000,7)
  (5000,8)
  (10000,9)
  (100000,10)}
;

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF8 encoding
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{every axis plot}
\pgfplotsset{grid style=dotted}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
    [clip marker paths=true,legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north},
    legend columns=2,
    xlabel=field amplitude,
    ylabel=losses,
    xmin=2e-3, xmax=5e-2,
    ymin=1e-4, ymax=1e-1,
    xtick={2e-3,5e-3,1e-2,2e-2,5e-2},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/sci},
    xticklabel={%
      \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\tick}%
      \pgfmathfloatexp{\pgfmathresult}%
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
    },
    grid=major
    ]

  \addplot+ coordinates
  {(0,1)
  (5,2)
  (10,3)
  (50,4)
  (100,5)
  (500,6)
  (1000,7)
  (5000,8)
  (10000,9)
  (100000,10)}
;

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was hoping for! Perfect! :)